# Spectrum of stars

Tags: visible-light, astrophysics, sun, stars

How does the spectrum of F type stars differ from our sun? I have tried to find the information on the internet but I haven't found anything that helps me. I need the information for a novel I am writing.

Comment: Check out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification What you want is about 1/3 of thevwat through, just under early and late stars.

Comment: You could consider posting in Astronomy SE instead.

Answer (score 0):

F type stars are in [this harvard classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#Harvard_spectral_classification), which depends on the temperature and the color of the star

[image: starclass]

The temperature of our sun(5772K seen) and color gives it  the classification G2 in the above scale you are asking about.

Comment: @ProfRob in my opinion the table does that, by showing that the only difference between the type F and the type of the sun is seen in the right collumns. .F stars have "medium" hydrogen lines, and G stars(the sun) weak.  both show the hydrogen spectrum

Comment: OK, I didn't spot that (because you didn't point that out). The Harvard classification is based on the appearance of the spectrum only. Not on the colour or temperature (which is inferred from modelling of the spectrum). The hydrogen line strength is just one of the differences. The same wikipedia article discusses those differences.

Answer (score 0):

The spectrum is different in the blackbody spectrum of the stars. F-type stars are hotter the G-type stars. Hence the peak of the blackbody spectrum will move towards shorter wavelengths.

I assum however that you are more interested in the spectrum taken of a srar across multiply waverlengths, and determining the absorption peaks. This will be basically the same for both types of stars but the intensities will vary and some different absorption lines may appear due to different intensities of certain wavelengths of light.